# Edicion base de datos

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

Estoy empezando con ASP.NET MVC en C#. He creado un crud para recetas que por  ahora me esta funcionando.
Mi objetivo ahora es que al crear una receta se cree una tabla con el nombre de la receta a partir de una matriz.Esta matriz tiene 4 campos y todas las recetas quiero que tengan ese campo, y luego al darle editar en el crud que tengo vaya  a visualizar la tabla que se ha creado a partir de la matriz y aparezcan los campos.

Las tabla de Receta sería así:

| ID | Nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | receta1 |
| 2 | receta2 |

La tabla matriz seria así:

| Agua | Harina | Aceite |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |

Una vez yo cree la receta también se creara la tabla con un

```sql
select * into "NOMBRERECETA_VERSION1" from MATRIZ
```

Y después al darle editar en la tabla de Receta quiero que me aparezcan los parámetros de la tabla NOMBRERECETA_VERSION1.

Gracias.

Comment: no. no necesitas eso. Las recetas no tienen que tener su propia tabla. Deberias tener varias tablas que contengan la informacion de la receta.

Comment: Lo hago así porque cada vez que edito una receta ya creada, creo una nueva versión y la nueva la mantengo pero le pongo un estado diferente de 1 para que no aparezca. Mas que nada este proyecto lo tenia en una aplicación de escritorio, y ahora la quiero pasar con la misma lógica de programa pero a web.

Comment: bueno, pero tu app de escritorio ya no estaba bien. Si tenes recetas con diferentes versiones, podrias agregar un campo version a la receta y listo... web o escritorio es lo mismo para el caso. No tiene nada que ver...

Comment: Nuuuu como vas a crear una tabla para cada receta! Tienes que tener una tabla Receta con `Id, Nombre, versión` y otra tabla Ingredientes con `Id, RecetaId, tipo_ingrediente, cantidad, ¿unidad?`

Comment: Es un proceso algo complejo que incluye otros programas aparte(TIA PORTAL principalmente), que necesita que sea de esa forma, se que no es la mejor manera pero tiene que ser de esa forma...Si solo dependiera de esa web, haría el cambio pero no es posible

Comment: Ok.. Y cuál es tu pregunta? No me quedó claro qué es lo que preguntas. Una cosa más... Si tienes 350 recetas, crearás 350 tablas en la base de datos?

Comment: No me queda clara cuál es tu pregunta. Si ya lo hiciste en escritorio, es replicar la misma lógica en la web. Si tienes un problema concreto con alguna parte, o un error, haría falta ver algo de código (un [mcve]) y el problema concreto o el error que estás teniendo.

Comment: Igual, por mas que dependas de otro programa, yo dudo muchisimo que TU programa tenga que hacer las cosas mal... puede que recibas mal la info, pero puedes arreglarla...

Comment: yo no recibo la info, yo simplemente genero la información de la forma que el otro programa necesita.Y no, no esta pensado para que haya 350 recetas. Suelen ser de aprox 20 tirando a producciones grandes.

Comment: Y en cuanto a la pregunta, en mi programa de escritorio al dar click en el boton de crear, aparte de crear la receta en la tabla Receta, tambien creaba a partir de la Matriz la tabla de esa receta en concreto, es lo que no estoy consiguiendo hacer.
Perdonad si no he formulado bien mi pregunta antes.

Comment: "no estoy consiguiendo hacer" es una mala descripción para cualquiera que sea la dificultad o el error que tienes. Digamos, no se sabe si no sabes responder al clic de un botón, si si lo sabes pero no sabes como ejecutar código en el servidor y no en el cliente (o al revés), o si lo sabes, pero no sabes como conectarte a una base de datos, o si obtienes algún error en alguno de estos casos. En otras palabras, describir lo que quieres lograr, sin mostrar código o un problema concreto, parece bien para un sitio de trabajo freelance, pero no para StackOverflow.

Comment: En el escenario que describe no veo ninguna razón para crear una tabla por cada receta eso no es nada adecuado. Pero si por alguna razón que no creo que exista pero bueno si por alguna razón tenga que ser así entonces una base de datos relacional no es la solución sino una como MongoDb para guardar cada receta como un documento por separado.

Comment: Quiero hacer eco de lo que propone Richard. *. . . una base de datos relacional no es la solución. . .* Mil veces esto. La propuesta de crear una tabla por receta es menos que ideal. Puedes terminar con 300 tablas que son diferentes variantes de `Recetas.ArrozConPollo_Version230_Revision40`. Si buscas "save recipes in database" obtienes EXCELENTES resultados con muy buenas propuestas. Si sigues pensando en crear una tabla por receta... Es una... *receta para el desastre* YEAAAAAAAH  B-)